# How do I set the okhttp 3 thread pool size

Tags: java, okhttp

Excuse me.I used okhttp as the network forwarding. The peak time of TPS is about 10000. I simulated the network and sent it 10,000 times.
Test case :

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)}{
    / / okhttp3  net forward
}
```

I then looked at the number of threads using Java visualvm and found that the number of threads was increasing and approaching the number of requests.When the number of requests reaches about 2000.The program has a memory overflow error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:714)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:949)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1371)
    at okhttp3.ConnectionPool.put(ConnectionPool.java:153)
    at okhttp3.OkHttpClient$1.put(OkHttpClient.java:163)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:266)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
    at com.nantian.easytrade.http.util.HttpCallHandle.execute(HttpCallHandle.java:331)
    at com.nantian.easytrade.http.util.HttpCallHandle.call(HttpCallHandle.java:191)
    at com.nantian.easytrade.http.util.HttpCallHandle.call(HttpCallHandle.java:176)
    at com.test.Main.main(Main.java:28)
```

As an android network request, this may not be a problem, but as a Java application making a request, the number of sending threads will be high at some point.Too many threads cause the application to process slowly or error.
Okhttp3 version is 3.11.0
Jdk version is 1.7

Comment: post the rest of the relevant code

Comment: Are you using 1 OkHttpClient or many?